# Changing SVG link object fill on hover with CSS

Tags: svg

I have an SVG object link on my page:

```
<a href="#" target="_blank">
        <object data="icons/email.svg" type="image/svg+xml" style="pointer-events: none;" class="icon">
                    gmail
        </object>
</a>
```

I'm trying to change the fill color on hover using this code in my SVG file:

```
<style>
    * {
      pointer-events: fill;
    }

    #email:hover path {
        fill:white;
    }
</style>
```

The problem is that the hover effect only works when I remove the style="pointer-events: none;" from the HTML, but the link only works when that code is there.

Any help is appreciated. I checked similar topics and wasn't able to find an answer to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Links only work when the contents of an `<object>` tag is non-interactive hence they work if pointer-events="none" and not otherwise.

For your use case you probably need to make the link internal to the SVG file i.e. via an SVG `<a>` tag in the SVG file rather than using an HTML link in the HTML file.

Comment: This worked by adding <a xlink:href="#" target="_blank">...</a> around the contents of the SVG file. Thank you!